# Send email automatically and append string before sending

Tags: android, email

I have an Android app which has an ability to genereta some reports and gives user an option to email those reports. After chooser opens and user picks Gmail to send an email, gmail app opens and user can see a message. It would be ideal if user would not be able to see a message becouse I would like to append a little commercial below a message and would not like to allow user to delete that small commercisl. For example:

Email body:

"Some generated report.

This report was generated by XYZ APP. Download app and create your own reports!"

The part which says which app generated report should be hidden somehow so user can't see it and that small advertisement is send together with the real message.

How can I accomplish that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I accomplish that?

Send the email yourself (JavaMail, via your Web server, etc.). If the user is sending the email, via the user's own email client and the user's own email account, the user has the right to see the message and edit it as desired.